# Setting AVAudioPlayer volume with a button

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find an answer for my problem.

I play multiple sounds on my app and I let the user to adjust the volume with a button. So if the user wants, he can play with .5 volume. So I have this code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Orchestra" ofType:@"mp3"];
theOrchestras = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error: NULL];
[theOrchestras play];
```

and to reduce the volume this:

```
- (IBAction) volumeReduced  {
    theOrchestras.volume = 0.5;
}
```

When the sounds is playing the volume is reduced, no problem. But when the sounds stops, and plays again, the volume always goes back to 1.

To fix this I tried to save the volume as an Integer, but for some reason the value is always 0, I couldn't make it work:

.m

```
 int64_t * volumeSaved;
```

.h

```
- (IBAction) volumeReduced  {
    volumeSaved = .5;
}

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Orchestra" ofType:@"mp3"];
theOrchestras = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error: NULL];
theOrchestras.volume = volumeSaved;
[theOrchestras play];
```

But the audio now always plays with 0 volume, muted.

Is there any way to do this with a button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `volumeSaved` as a pointer to an integer instead of an integer, but then assigning to it like it's an integer. That's one oddity.

But your real problem is that the [`volume` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/volume) in `AVAudioPlayer` is a `float`, not a `int64_t`. So change the type to:

```
float volumeSaved;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try storing the volume with NSNumber.